# What is the difference between ethers.getDefaultProvider() and providers.EtherscanProvider() in ethersjs?

Tags: etherscan, web3-providers, ethers.js

What is the difference between ethers.getDefaultProvider() and providers.EtherscanProvider() in ethersjs and when should you use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [ethers docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v4/api-providers.html),

`ethers.getDefaultProvider()` connects you to a node on the ethereum network. Use it when you want to interact directly with the blockchain.

`new ethers.providers.EtherscanProvider()` connects you to the [Etherscan blockchain web service API](https://etherscan.io/apis). Use it if you only want data from the Etherscan web service API.

Answer (score 0):

`ethers.getDefaultProvider()` is meant basically for prototyping and testing.  When you connect to a specific provider with your own API key, you have better performance and access to communication metrics. ([see docs)](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api-keys/)

> These API keys are provided as a community resource by the backend
> services for low-traffic projects and for early prototyping.
>
> Since these [default provider] API keys are shared by all users (that
> have not acquired their own API key), they are aggressively throttled
> which means retries occur more frequently and the responses are
> slower.
>
> It is highly recommended that you sign up for a free API key from each
> service for their free tier, which (depending on the service) includes
> many advantages:
>
> - a much higher request rate and concurrent request limit
> - faster responses with fewer retries and timeouts
> - useful metric tracking for performance tuning and to analyze your customer behaviour
> - more advanced APIs, such as archive data or advanced log queries

For example, to connect to an Infura node on the Ropsten test network:

`let provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider("ropsten", infuraProjectID);`

And for WebSockets:

`let infuraRopstenWSProvider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider.getWebSocketProvider("ropsten", process.env.RPC_INFURA_PROJECTID);`

You can also use a simper JRPC URL, however JRPC connections are read-only:

`let JRPC_infuraRopstenProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC_INFURA_HTTP_ROPSTEN_URL);`

Here is also a nice [Ethers.js Cheat Sheet](https://dev.to/hideckies/ethers-js-cheat-sheet-1h5j) for other functions.